# discordpy, bot crashs after simulate a lottery

Tags: python, discord.py

I made this simulation as a discordpy cog, but the bot goes offline and the console is open and don't do anything if I write or quit it...
At an amount of 15000 the bot crashes, what can I do, why it crashs?
There are discord emojies, which are selected randomly and there are different chances with the numbers etc. I hope somebody can help me here!

```
    @bot.command()
    async def simulate(self, ctx, amount):
        wnitro = 0
        wkey = 0
        wgold = 0
        wred = 0
        wblue = 0
        wgreen = 0
        wgrey = 0
        for zaehler in range(1, int(amount)):
            drehungen = randint(5, 20)
            gone = randint(1, 1000)
            gtwo = randint(1, 1000)
            gthree = randint(1, 1000)
            gfour = randint(1, 1000)
            gfive = randint(1, 1000)
            gsix = randint(1, 1000)
            gseven = randint(1, 1000)
            geight = randint(1, 1000)
            gnine = randint(1, 1000)
            randomitem = [gone, gtwo, gthree, gfour, gfive, gsix, gseven, geight, gnine]
            slots = []
            for item in range(len(randomitem)):
                if randomitem[item] >= 950:
                    slots.append("<a:classic:802844186026049546>")
                elif randomitem[item] >= 850:
                    slots.append("<a:geld:770235576539676682>")
                elif randomitem[item] >= 800:
                    slots.append("<a:goldendia:802976550995755019>")
                elif randomitem[item] >= 650:
                    slots.append("<a:darkbluedia:802976435500875836>")
                elif randomitem[item] >= 500:
                    slots.append("<a:reddia:802873281841463296>")
                elif randomitem[item] >= 300:
                    slots.append("<a:greendia:802875898353156138>")
                else:
                    slots.append("<a:greydia:802977070627553311>")
            cdrehung = 1
            nitroextra = randint(1, 100)
            keyextra = randint(1, 10)
            coinsextra = randint(1, 5)
            coins2extra = randint(1, 2)
            i = 0
            while i < drehungen:
                if cdrehung == 0:
                    gewinn = slots[4]
                elif cdrehung == 1:
                    gewinn = slots[5]
                elif cdrehung == 2:
                    gewinn = slots[6]
                elif cdrehung == 3:
                    gewinn = slots[7]
                elif cdrehung == 4:
                    gewinn = slots[8]
                elif cdrehung == 5:
                    gewinn = slots[0]
                elif cdrehung == 6:
                    gewinn = slots[1]
                elif cdrehung == 7:
                    gewinn = slots[2]
                elif cdrehung == 8:
                    gewinn = slots[3]
                    cdrehung -= 9
                cdrehung += 1
                i += 1
                if i == drehungen:
                    if gewinn == "<a:classic:802844186026049546>":
                        if nitroextra == 1:
                            wnitro += 1
                        else:
                            drehungen += 1
                    elif gewinn == "<a:geld:770235576539676682>":
                        if keyextra == 1:
                            wkey += 1
                        else:
                            drehungen += 1
                    elif gewinn == "<a:goldendia:802976550995755019>":
                        if coinsextra == 1:
                            wgold += 1
                        else:
                            drehungen += 1
                    elif gewinn == "<a:darkbluedia:802976435500875836>":
                        if coins2extra == 1:
                            wblue += 1
                        else:
                            drehungen += 1
                    elif gewinn == "<a:reddia:802873281841463296>":
                        wred += 1
                    elif gewinn == "<a:greendia:802875898353156138>":
                        wgreen += 1
                    elif gewinn == "<a:greydia:802977070627553311>":
                        wgrey += 1
        await ctx.send(f"There are the results out of `{str(amount)}x` spins: {str(wnitro)}x Nitro, {str(wkey)} Key, {str(wgold)} <a:goldendia:802976550995755019>, {str(wblue)} <a:darkbluedia:802976435500875836>, {str(wred)} <a:reddia:802873281841463296>, {str(wgreen)}<a:greendia:802875898353156138>, {str(wgrey)}<a:greydia:802977070627553311>")
```

thanks to everyone who helps c:

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: nope, that's the problem, I don't get any error and console is dead or sth like that...

Comment: But does the script end? Or is it still running?

Comment: the bot is when I look at discord down, so offline, but if I look in my console I can't stop it with STRG + C

so I had to close the screen with: ```screen -X -S "mybot" quit```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I take it back, theoretically your slots could all be the same thing, or a combination of things that cause `drehungen` to always implement.  You really need to reconsider the logic on your loop.

Update: actually that is false, you do update `cdrehung` which updates `gewinn`... this is pretty convoluted, but it does seems like it should have to end at some point.  That being said this loop is a bit complicated, I would consider some debug messages for all these different variables to figure out what is going on.

Just looking at it, inside your while loop the state of `gewinn` doesn't change, or any of the other items (`wnitro wkey wgold wblue`)... sooo if that is the case it *could* mean that `drehungen` is always being incremented... which means `i == drehungen` is always true... which means an infinite loop.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I already tested, that the variable "i" gets at one point higher and higher and I don't know why, will make more variables!

Comment: well thats in your code, you always increment i.  It's drehung you need to figure out.

Comment: yeah thanks, will work on it now and see how I can fix it, thanks for the help!

Edit:
I've fixxed it!